# Find the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have to find the value of the integral $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}$$ I was able to can write it as $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{4}) }$$

But I cannot go any further.

**Edit:** Also I am looking for a short method

Comment: Following Lab's answer below (which is a quick approach), you can find the anti derivative of $\frac{1}{sinx+cosx}$ through tangent half angle substitution OR use a standard anti derivative for $cscx$ where the $x$ is read as $x+\pi/4$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

Using $\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx,$

$$I+I=\dfrac1{\sqrt2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{dx}{\sin\left(x+\dfrac\pi4\right)}$$

Hope you can take it from here?

Comment: I think your speed of typing is faster than my speed of thinking...:)

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thanks